# Markers icons cropped on zoom Google Maps for Rails (gmaps4rails)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

I'm using gmaps4rails to create an application and I'm with one problem. 
When I zoom (in or out) map the icons are cropped.

[image: Cropped markers]

This is my method to show markers:

```
def gmaps4rails_marker_picture
{
    "picture" => "/assets/pins/pin_#{tipo_assalto_id}.png",          
    "width" => "32" ,         
    "height" => "32",
    "marker_anchor" => [12,34],
    "shadow_picture" => "http://www.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png",
    "shadow_width" => "58" ,    
    "shadow_height" =>  "42",   
    "shadow_anchor" => [6,38]

}
end
```

Somebody can help me in this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys, sorry because my ignorance. I set width, and height like as string instead a int. 
Fixing:

```
def gmaps4rails_marker_picture
{
"picture" => "/assets/pins/pin_#{tipo_assalto_id}.png",          
"width" => 32 ,         
"height" => 32,
"marker_anchor" => [12,34],
"shadow_picture" => "http://www.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png",
"shadow_width" => 58 ,    
"shadow_height" =>  42,   
"shadow_anchor" => [6,38]
}
end
```

Comment: Glad you found a solution! Accept your answer so other people will see your question as solved.